# populate combobox items from c++ file in Qt quick

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qml

I am a novice in QT QML.
I have a list of strings in a c++ file(audioinput.cpp) and one combo-box in a QML file(voiceCall.qml).
I need to populate items of this combo-box with strings of that list .

my list definition is ->

```
List<Qstring> lst .
```

my combobox defintion is :

```
ComboBox {
         id: comboBox
         x: 200
         y: 95
         objectName:  "speakers"
         width: 244
         height: 32
         model: []
}
```

Comment: Please read the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html) about rootContext properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++:

```
QQuickView view;
QStringList comboBoxModel = { "one", "two", "three" };
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("comboBoxModel", &comboBoxModel);
view.setSource("main.qml");
view.show();
```

QML:

```
Combobox {
    model: comboBoxModel
}
```

QStringList inherits from QList<QString>.